# Does using union-find in Kruskal's algorithm actually affect worst-case runtime?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, graph-algorithm

So I'm teaching myself some graph algorithms, now on Kruskal's, and understand that it's recommended to use union-find so checking whether adding an edge creates a cycle only takes O(Log V) time. For practical purposes, I see why you'd want to, but strictly looking through Big O notation, does doing so actually affect the worst-case complexity?

My reasoning: If instead of union find, we did a DFS to check for cycles, the runtime for that would be O(E+V), and you have to perform that V times for a runtime of O(V^2 + VE). It's more than with union find, which would be O(V * LogV), but the bulk of the complexity of Kruskal's comes from deleting the minimum element of the priority queue E times, which is O(E * logE), the Big O answer. I don't really see a space advantage either since the union-find takes O(V) space and so too do the data structures you need to maintain to find a cycle using DFS.

So a probably overly long explanation for a simple question: Does using union-find in Kruskal's algorithm actually affect worst-case runtime?

Comment: Your question has one major flaw, the DFS wouldn't be executed only V times, but potentially O(E) times, as there are E edges to be evaluated. And the bulk of Kruskal complexity is the edge sorting. You can use a priority queue for that, but it's not required.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly where I was off. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> and understand that it's recommended to use union-find so checking whether adding an edge creates a cycle only takes O(Log V) time

This isn't right. Using [union find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) is `O(alpha(n) * m)`, where `alpha(n)` is the inverse of the Ackermann function, and, for all intents and purposes, can be considered constant. So much faster than logarithmic:

> Since `alpha(n)` is the inverse of this function, `alpha(n)` is less than 5 for all remotely practical values of `n`. Thus, the amortized running time per operation is effectively a small constant.

---

> but the bulk of the complexity of Kruskal's comes from deleting the minimum element of the priority queue E times

This is also wrong. [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) does not involve using any priority queues. It involves sorting the edges by cost at the beginning. Although the complexity remains the one you mention for this step. However, sorting might be faster in practice than a priority queue (using a priority queue will, at best, be equivalent to a heap sort, which is not the fastest sorting algorithm).

Bottom line, if `m` is the number of edges and `n` the number of nodes.:

1. Sorting the edges: `O(m log m)`.
2. For each edge, calling `union-find`: `O(m * alpha(n))`, or basically just `O(m)`.
3. Total complexity: `O(m log m + m * alpha(n))`.
4. If you don't use union-find, total complexity will be `O(m log m + m * (n + m))`, if we use your `O(n + m)` cycle finding algorithm. Although `O(n + m)` for this step is probably an understatement, since you must also update your structure somehow (insert an edge). The naive disjoint-set algorithm is actually `O(n log n)`, so even worse.

**Note:** in this case, you can write `log n` instead of `log m` if you prefer, because `m = O(n^2)` and `log(n^2) = 2log n`.

In conclusion: yes, union-find helps **a lot**.

Even if you use the `O(log n)` variant of union-find, which would lead to `O(m log m + m log n)` total complexity, which you could assimilate to `O(m log m)`, in practice you'd rather keep the second part faster if you can. Since union-find is very easy to implement, there's really no reason not to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don't see how it couldn't be implemented both ways as they both give you a means to access the minimum element in O(ElogE) time (priority queue through deleting the min element E times, and sorting just by using a O(ElogE) sort). Either way, my question still stands. Since the bulk of the complexity is from something that is O(ELogE), either through the priority queue or sorting, then does union find actually make a difference to worst-case time complexity?

Comment: @ChirayuPoudel Union-find has nothing to do with accessing the min element

Comment: @ChirayuPoudel I have added more details. Please let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Just one little detail: As m is O(n^2), O(m log m) = O(m log n), because O(m log n^2) = O(2 m log n)